# Is there a formula for $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\Big(|f(x)|^{s}f(x)\Big)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable  at least of order $m$. Is there a formula to compute $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\Big(|f(x)|^{s}f(x)\Big)\  (s\in N) ?$  My attempt by general Leibniz's rule was not successful and the result is so complicated and useless to me. Thanks a lot for any other guidance.

Comment: Have you perhaps considered working with the Fourier transform?

Comment: No. how? Do you know how?

Comment: @Tom Nice hint!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I use that?

Comment: Fast, @FourierTransform!

Comment: OP, a Fourier transform will "transform" differentiation into multiplication, potentially making your analysis easier. Take a look at the functional relationships on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform.

Comment: But since $f$ is unknown it seems that Fourier transform can not be applied.